# segmentation fault (core dumped) caused by ros::spinOnce?

Tags: ros, callback, spinonce

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In these days, I spent all my time with coding, but there always problems with me, the newbie to ROS. And I try to search the answer here, but I still need some help.

For the question, main point is that I need to grab a picture from ROS message, then do some image processing, then grab another one.....

when I try to get cvimage from ROS, I use the callback function which is called by  `ros::spin()`. Then the program will always stay in callback function. So I try to do it with several ways.

The first method, I use `ros::spin()` to call the callback function and get a frame, then I use `ros::shutdown()` in order to  exit the callback function. This method is works, but for each frame I need to init the ros again with `ros::init(argc,argv,"XXX")` and redefine the node....So the final result is unsatisfactory because init the ros again cost a long time.

The second way, I try to deal the callback function with `ros::spinOnce()`, it also works when I don't attend the image processing part.(I can get the frame and show it) Then I add the image processing part, it show the qustion "segmentation fault". According to some related question, I add `launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args"` in the launch file, the final result is:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main( argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x4>,argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x4>)
```

So could someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64129/segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)-caused-by-ros::spinonce?/) by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard design approach is to put your image processing steps in a callback, then call `ros::spin()` in the main program, as shown [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node).

You should **not** need to call `ros::shutdown() and ros::init()` for every callback.  If your code is getting stuck in the callback function, then the issue probably lies with the contents of your callback.  If you post the callback function here, we might be able to help.

**Edit:**
I still don't quite understand your issues.  It would help if you could provide more detail in your original question: callback code, what you expect to see, what is actually happening, etc.

If your callback takes longer to execute than new messages are received, the new messages will be buffered by ROS behind the scenes.  Your callback should *not* be interrupted when new messages are received.  The messages will be delivered in the order received, as long as there is space remaining in the message buffer.  Eventually, when the message buffer is full, the oldest message will be dropped to make room for new messages.  If you always want to process the last-received message, set the queue size to 1 in the `ros::subscriber` constructor.

So, if your intent is to always process the most-recent image, you shouldn't need to worry about how long your image-processing steps take.  Set the subscriber queue size to 1, and ROS will automatically call your callback with the most-recent message as soon as you've finished processing the previous image.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on 2013-06-01**:
Yes, at first, I try to realize image processing in the callback function, but thereis a problem that the image processing(last for maybe 50ms) will be distrub by the next image and the data will be refresh earlier than I want.

**Comment by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on 2013-06-01**:
As I described in the beginning of thequestion, I need grabbing image then do processing. But not trigger by the each image passively.

**Comment by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on 2013-06-01**:
So now mine method is getting cvImage in the callback function and process it in another function. And there is still the question I asked.

**Comment by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on 2013-06-01**:
To be honest, I have the same thought as you described in the answer, but when I use this method(http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages), the image will always be refreshed.

**Comment by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on 2013-06-01**:
Now I am trying to not use a calss(http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages), I hope it will works. Thank you!

**Comment by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on 2013-06-02**:
Fine, I finally solve the problem! Thank you ~~